# Google Script/Sheets - Twitter API Integration POST statuses/update in_reply_to_status_id

Tags: twitter, google-ads-api

I am not a developer so I apologize in advance if my question is really basic. I've managed to successfully install this Google script Twitter API integration below and send tweets from a Google sheet (the code was offered  [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/twitter-oauth10)). I simply use `=sendTweet(message)` in a cell, replacing `message` with the cell reference of where i have the text for the tweet, for example `=sendTweet(C6)` and the new Tweet will contain the pre-prepared text in cell `C6`.

What i'm trying to do is to add to the script the option of sending a tweet in reply to another tweet. Reading on [Twitter's API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update), I understand that the `in_reply_to_status_id` parameter needs to pass the `in_reply_to_status_id` in the API call URL but that's as far as my understanding goes.

I don't know how to define this new tweet_id variable and how to get it to pass the `in_reply_to_status_id=tweet_id` string in the right place so it will function. The ideal would be to use the same formula but with the addition of `tweet_id` for the reply, as a second variable. For example `=sendTweet(message, tweet_id)`.

Your help would be much appreciated

```
// User-level Twitter API request
// Requires the OAuth1 library to be pasted into the script.
// https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/oauth10-library

var CONSUMER_KEY = '************************';
var CONSUMER_SECRET = '************************';
var ACCESS_TOKEN = '************************';
var ACCESS_SECRET = '************************';

/**
 * Sends a tweet.
 * @param {string} message The message to send.
 * @return {?Object} The complex response object with the status of the send
 *     request. See https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update
 *     for the structure of this object.
 */
function sendTweet(message) {
  if (typeof OAuth1 === 'undefined') {
    var libUrl = 'https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/oauth10-library';
    throw Error('OAuth1 library not found. Please take a copy of the OAuth1 ' +
        'library from ' + libUrl + ' and append to the bottom of this script.');
  }
  var params = '';
  var tweet = message.substring(0, 160);
  var options = {method: 'POST', payload: {status: tweet}};
  var authUrlFetch = OAuth1.withAccessToken(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET);
  var response = authUrlFetch.fetch('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', params, options);
  var responseText = response.getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to

1. add `tweet_id` as an argument in your function signature

```
function sendTweet(message, tweet_id) { }
```

2. and then include it in the payload.

```
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  payload: {
    status: tweet,
    in_reply_to_status_id: tweet_id
  }
};
```

Full code:

```
// User-level Twitter API request
// Requires the OAuth1 library to be pasted into the script.
// https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/oauth10-library

var CONSUMER_KEY = '************************';
var CONSUMER_SECRET = '************************';
var ACCESS_TOKEN = '************************';
var ACCESS_SECRET = '************************';

/**
 * Sends a tweet.
 * @param {string} message The message to send.
 * @param {string} [tweet_id] - The ID of an existing status that
 *     the update is in reply to. Note: This parameter will be ignored unless
 *     the author of the Tweet this parameter references is mentioned within
 *     the status text. Therefore, you must include @username , where username
 *     is the author of the referenced Tweet, within the update.
 * @return {?Object} The complex response object with the status of the send
 *     request. See https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update
 *     for the structure of this object.
 */
function sendTweet(message, tweet_id) {
  if (typeof OAuth1 === 'undefined') {
    var libUrl = 'https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/oauth10-library';
    throw Error('OAuth1 library not found. Please take a copy of the OAuth1 ' +
        'library from ' + libUrl + ' and append to the bottom of this script.');
  }
  var params = '';
  var tweet = message.substring(0, 160);
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    payload: {
      status: tweet,
      in_reply_to_status_id: tweet_id
    }
  };
  var authUrlFetch = OAuth1.withAccessToken(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET);
  var response = authUrlFetch.fetch('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', params, options);
  var responseText = response.getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(responseText);
}
```

Full disclaimer, I haven't setup Twitter API access for myself to verify that this works. Please let me know if you have issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer... Tweet goes out with text in "message" however not as a reply... just like before, a stand alone tweet

Comment: Strange, I tried following your method and passed another option (url) and twitter accept it. It is just the in_reply_to_twitter_id that it doesn't count for some reason.
`  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    payload: {
      in_reply_to_status_id: tweet_id,
      status: tweet,
      attachment_url: url
    }`

Comment: @EladRatson Did you include the username mention in the tweet? Recall the documentation stating: "**Note:** This parameter will be ignored unless the author of the Tweet this parameter references is mentioned within the status text. Therefore, you must include `@username` , where `username` is the author of the referenced Tweet, within the update."

Comment: Hi @Diego, looking for a way to contact you. Should you have a moment, could you please have a look at this (I'm using the same code but for another API call): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65256374/google-script-sheets-twitter-api-integration-post-direct-messages-events-n